# Why doesn't DefaultSignatures allow concrete types?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
class C a where
  f :: [a]
  default f :: (Num a) => [a]
  f = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

The above works, the below doesn't. It seems `DefaultSignatures` extension only allows specifying constraints, but not substituting a concrete type. Section [*Default Method Signatures*](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#default-method-signatures) of the *GHC Users Guide* doesn't explain this. Why doesn't `DefaultSignatures` allow me to substitute a concrete type? What is the rationale? Where can I read more on how and why `DefaultSignatures` are implemented?

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
class C a where
  f :: [a]
  default f :: [Int]
  f = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Can't reproduce with GHC 8.0.1. The below code compiles file for me.

Comment: ...it seems utterly useless though, but I suppose your actual use case is less trivial?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using GHC 8.0.2 then you should write it in different way because there was type checker regression for those kinds of types. See notes:

https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/8.0.2-notes.html

So you need to write it like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class C a where
  f :: [a]
  default f :: (a ~ Int) => [a]
  f = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Instead of saying that `f` has type of list of `Int`s, you need to say, that `f` has type of lists of some type `a` where `a` is `Int`. `{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}` language extension is needed to enable type equalities. It's not what it's used for but it is required. Compiles for GHC 8.0.2

Comment: Thanks! But what is the motivation for such a restriction?

Comment: Well, as it seems, it wasn't intentional. It was just a bug that previous version compiled perfectly. See this ticket for details: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12784 My guess is that it's easier for type inference algorithm solve constraints and choose appropriate signature. Another useful example of this feature: http://chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-constraint-trick